# Why my auto completion script (jquery) did not work on my website?

Tags: php, jquery

I have downloaded an auto completion(jQuery script) form from net. I am using wamp phpmyadmin server for testing my website(php and mysql) in my computer. When i used the auto completion form in my wamp server it is working properly but when i uploaded to actual website server the script is not working. I am not able to find the problem, its showing no error. can you help me

this is my html script

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="js/autocomplete.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/autocomplete.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $().ready(function() {
          $("#name").autocomplete("php/autocompletion.php",{
              width: 260,
              matchContains: true,
              //mustMatch: true,
              //minChars: 0,
              //multiple: true,
              //highlight: false,
              //multipleSeparator: ",",
              selectFirst: false
          });
      });
  </script>
```

autocompletion.php file

```
  <?php
  $host="localhost"; // Host name
  $username="name"; // Mysql username
  $password="password"; // Mysql password
  $db_name="dbname"; // Database name

  $con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)   or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db($db_name, $con)  or die(mysql_error());

  $q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
  if (!$q) return;

  $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT 'name' AS 'name' FROM 'name' Where 'name' LIKE '%$q%'";
  $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
  while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
      $cname = $rs['name'];
      echo "$cname\n";
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: It looks like you might be able to test the ajax responder by putting "your-domain.com/php/autocomplete.php?q=test" in the URL. Have you tried that? (You might need to set display_errors and error_reporting.)

Comment: are both servers running the exact same configration?

Comment: What is server's error-log showing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this at ready function `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: OP is already using `$().ready(function() {` in his code. How exactly you think that this is an answer ?

Comment: he forgot to put document in the **()**

Answer (score 1):

if it works in your own server, but not in the website maybe the url you provided is not located in the same place of the website. Are you sure php/autocompletion.php is called in the server. It can have a BASE_HREF os something in the html that causes not to find the correct path.

Try to put the url complete http://myserver.com/php/autocompletion.php and previously try to call the php from the browser to see the results. http://myserver.com/php/autocompletion.php?q=word